# Modal settings don't work when dynamically calling modals [materialize]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, material-design, materialize

I have the following code:

```
 $( document).ready(function() {
 $('.modal').modal( {
     dismissible: false, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
     opacity: 1, // Opacity of modal background
     inDuration: 300, // Transition in duration
     outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
     startingTop: '4%', // Starting top style attribute
     endingTop: '10%', // Ending top style attribute
 }
```

The options within the function above (example: opacity) never works whenever the modal is opened dynamically, for example using the following code:

```
$('#modal1').modal('open');
```

It only works when selecting a modal trigger:

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1">Modal</a>
```

What is causing this and how can I resolve this issue?

**EDIT!**

For clarification, the modal is displayed using both methods, however, with

> $('#modal1').modal('open');

the modal doesn't adhere to the features example the opacity or inDuration.

Comment: So you want that the JQuery code shows the modal? Not when you press a button?

Comment: one question are you aware of there is a mistake in your code? You wrote .modal instead of #modal

Comment: @Steven There is no error. Please refer to this document http://materializecss.com/modals.html before attempting to provide an answer to this question.

Comment: Tip next time make it clear for people in your question that you use Materializecss I taught it was a bootstrap question

Comment: @Steven Notice it says materialize in the tags.

Comment: Yes in the tags but not in the title or the question you speak of I use Materialze so next time made it clear so it won't happen again. The tags or to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute a callback function in the modal options like this:

```
$( document).ready(function() {
  function someFunction(){
    $('#modal1').modal('open');
  }
  $('.modal').modal( {
    dismissible: false, // Modal can be dismissed by clicking outside of the modal
    opacity: 1, // Opacity of modal background
    inDuration: 300, // Transition in duration
    outDuration: 200, // Transition out duration
    startingTop: '4%', // Starting top style attribute
    endingTop: '10%', // Ending top style attribute
    ready: someFunction
  }
```

> **EDIT**: Here's a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ffphwq27/3/)
>
> The code above is not working, indeed. In this fiddle I simply replaced the $(document).ready function with IIFE. Options are working for me, when you simply call the modal without any triggers.

Comment: This still doesn't solve my question Your JSFiddle utilizes a button. My description clearly states that my issue isn't whenever the modal is opened using a modal-trigger, my issue is when it is called dynamically.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. From what I've understood, this is what you seek. Made a new edit to the JSFiddle.

Comment: It's still not working for me, I don't know why. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: Does the modal open with its default options when you open the fiddle? I mean is everything okay in the fiddle, but not working on your original code, or it still runs with inDuration:300 even though its configured on 5000?

Comment: The Fiddle works just fine. In my code, it doesn't work. Pro grammatically opening the modal opens the model in the default options

Comment: It seems that the problem is somewhere with the references. Can you post where you include your materialize js and css files.

Comment: How do you try to call the modal, is it attached to an event? Maybe the problem isn't caused by the modal, but by the event you are trying to call it with?